# Find the volume of the region defined by $|x|+|y|+|z|<4$

Tags: graphics3d, regions, inequalities

I want to find the volume of the region defined by the following inequality:

$\quad \quad |x|+|y|+|z|<4$

In addition to calculating the volume of this region, I would also like to be able to obtain its representation as a plot.

I have started by plotting the vertices, i.e., the points (4, 0, 0), (-4, 0, 0), (0, 4, 0), (0, -4, 0), (0, 0, 4), and (0, 0, -4), but I am not sure how to continue from there.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest that: 1) You take the introductory [Tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour) now! 2) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)! 3) As you receive help, try to give it too, by answering questions in your area of expertise.

Comment: @julie You may want to consider accepting one of the answers that have been provided below, if they solve your problem.

Answer (score 5):

```
volume = Integrate[1,  Element[{x, y, z}, ImplicitRegion[Abs[x] + Abs[y] + Abs[z] < 4, {x, y, z}]]]

(*256/3*)

ContourPlot3D[Abs[x] + Abs[y] + Abs[z] == 4, {x, -5, 5}, {y, -5, 5}, {z, -5, 5}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

### A small addition from *Mathematica* v. 10

In his answer @Ivan has already nailed the most important part of the question, i.e. the formal representation of your region as an `ImplicitRegion` object:

```
region = ImplicitRegion[Abs[x] + Abs[y] + Abs[z] < 4, {x, y, z}]
```

I just wanted to add that, if you are on *Mathematica* 10 or newer, you can also use the `RegionMeasure` or `Volume` functions to calculate the volume of a region:

```
RegionMeasure[region]
Volume[region]

(* 256/3 *)
```

### How to arrive at the shape of this region

In response to @julie's question in the comment, here is how one can imagine constructing the 3D region.

Consider the corresponding *equality* in 2D, disregard  the absolute values for now, and let's just concentration on the first quadrant ($x>=0$,$y>=0$). The resulting $x + y = 4$ is just the equation of a line, i.e. $y = 4 - x$. The region in the first quadrant in which the *inequality* $x+y<4$ holds is the region between that line and the axes:

```
RegionPlot[
  x + y < 4 && x >= 0 && y >= 0, 
  {x, -5, 5}, {y, -5, 5},
  Axes -> True, Frame -> False
]
```

[image: Triangle x+y<4 in the first quadrant]

Taking the absolute value of $x$ is geometrically equivalent to mirroring that triangle with respect to the $y$ axis as shown below. Since we are taking its absolute value, we will also remove the $x>=0$ restriction.

```
RegionPlot[
  Abs[x] + y < 4 && y >= 0,
  {x, -5, 5}, {y, -5, 5},
  Axes -> True, Frame -> False
]
```

[image: Triangle Abs[x]+y<4]

Taking the absolute value of $y$ is similarly equivalent to mirroring this figure with respect to the $x$ axis. The result is the square region below:

```
RegionPlot[
  Abs[x] + Abs[y] < 4,
  {x, -5, 5}, {y, -5, 5},
  Axes -> True, Frame -> False
]
```

[image: Square with Abs[x]+Abs[y]<4]

In the three-dimensional case, you can work your way through in a similar way: $x+y+z=4$ is the equation of a plane that defines a trangular wedge in the first quadrant, and so forth.

As for the numerical value, you could consider that your figure is made up of two square pyramids. The volume of a square pyramid is $V=a^2h/3$ where $a$ is the length of the base edge, and $h$ is the height. In your case, you can calculate the base edge as the hypotenuse of the smallest 2D triangle we introduced above ($a^2=4^2+4^2=32$), and the height of the pyramid is 4. The volume of this pyramid is 128/3, and your figure is made of two such pyramids, so $2\times128/3 = 256/3$.

Comment: thank you! but how was the final answer calculated? how did you know what all the sides were and where those points went?

Comment: @julie I amended my answer to include a way to construct the region. Let me know if that answers your question appropriately.

Answer (score 2):

An alternate approach to calculating the volume

```
Integrate[
 Boole[Abs[x] + Abs[y] + Abs[z] < 4],
 {x, -Infinity, Infinity},
 {y, -Infinity, Infinity},
 {z, -Infinity, Infinity}]
```

> 256/3

Answer (score 1):

As a cone (with a square base), the volume is one-third the base times the height: `1/3 * (4 Sqrt[2])^2 * 8`.

Another plot, based on the OP's coordinates:

```
ConvexHullMesh@Join[4 IdentityMatrix[3], -4 IdentityMatrix[3]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]